# datetime TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, datetime, string-formatting, netdna-api

I am sure there are easier ways to do this, but I am not sure why I keep getting a TypeError.

```
   import datetime
   getdate = datetime.date.today()
   thirty = datetime.timedelta(days=30)
   last_month = getdate - thirty
   print json.dumps(api.get_zone_stats(3, "daily", "%s", "%s" %(last_month, getdate)))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
...

**TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
api.get_zone_stats(3, "daily", "%s", "%s" %(last_month, getdate))
```

The `%` operator works on the previous string only:

```
"%s" %(last_month, getdate)
```

You have two variables for one single `%s`.

Try this:

```
api.get_zone_stats(3, "daily", "{0}".format(last_month), "{0}".format(getdate))
```

or this:

```
api.get_zone_stats(3, "daily", str(last_month), str(getdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, you're trying to format a string with two values but the string contains only one fill-in-spot:

```
print json.dumps(api.get_zone_stats(3, "daily", "%s", "%s" %(last_month, getdate)))
```

Did you mean the following?

```
print json.dumps(api.get_zone_stats(3, "daily", str(last_month), str(getdata)))
```